# admin.site.register(Question) doesn't work

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

i am new to Django and python, and i want to start django admin with official exercises

i'm okay with running server. but questions doesn't show up.

my code is :

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Question

admin.site.register(Question)
```

thank you for reading my question

Comment: Check the user permissions to view the model admin section

Comment: Check whether you have added your app in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` file.

Comment: @PyMaster i added apps to INSTALLED_APPS and add some code to models.py and then i solve it. thank you for the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You should have a model named Question in your app's models.py file

2)You should run makemigrations and migrate commands

Answer (score 1):

Want to have something like this, check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/ for more info

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Question

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

create a Question model class in models.py with the necessary fields then run makemigrations and migrate commands. Example question model is:

```
class Question(models.Model):
      question_id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True,primary_key=True)
      name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


      def __str__(self):
           return self.name

      class Meta:
           verbose_name_plural="question"
```